# Create a const Eigen (Eigen_Library) Matrix REVISITED

Tags: c++, vector, constants, eigen, abaqus

i have an problem with definining some constant Eigen (eigen.tuxfamily.org) Vectors in a header file, but obviously it's more a compiler problem than an Eigen-specific problem..

Defining this in a header file:

```
const double[] hardcodedData = {1,2,3};
const Vector3d myConstVector(hardcodedData);
```

works perfectly using Microsoft VC2010 via cython/distutils (which i use for testing).
Once the header file is included, i can access myConstVectory from every function/method/whatever and use it for calculations..

Using the same code with:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x64

which is called by ABAQUS 6.13-2 , a finite element software,

every const Vector is initialized with zeros! Until now, i found no workaround except using something like this:

```
const Vector3d myConstVector()
{
    const static Vector3d vec(hardcodedData);
    return vec;
}
```

This workaround is OK, but not really what i intended to do .. Also it has some overhead.

Is there a clean solution, to get the "hardcoded" option running? Thx in advance!

Comment: Seems to work fine in Version 17.00.61030 for x86 (VS2012), although my line reads `const double hardcodedData[] = {1,2,3};`.

Comment: Creating a simple console app in VS2012, it also works perfect, so i think some sort of compiler setting must be the reason. Really an akward problem ..

Comment: Then you're going to have to supply the compiler settings...

Comment: from the ABAQUS environment file:

`compile_cpp=['cl', '/c', '/W0', '/MD', '/TP',
             '/EHsc', '/DNDEBUG', '/DWIN32', '/DTP_IP', '/D_CONSOLE',
             '/DNTI', '/DFLT_LIC', '/DOL_DOC', '/D__LIB__', '/DHKS_NT',
             '/DABQ_NTI_NET', '/DFAR=', '/D_WINDOWS', '/DABQ_WIN86_64',

             # '/O1', # <-- Optimization

             # '/Zi', # <-- Debug symbols

             '/I%I']`